# How to check the nearest matching value between two fields in same table and add data to the third field using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have one table:

| Index | Month_1 | Month_2 | Paid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 12 | 10 |  |
| 02 | 09 | 03 |  |
| 03 | 02 | 04 |  |
| 04 | 01 | 08 |  |

The output should be:

| Index | Month_1 | Month_2 | Paid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 12 | 10 | Yes |
| 02 | 09 | 03 |  |
| 03 | 02 | 04 | Yes |
| 04 | 01 | 08 |  |

Logic: Add 'Yes' to the Paid field whose Month_1 and Month_2 are nearby

Comment: how close is "nearby"? i assume you mean -- as i see in the title of your question -- that the values from the two columns are as close as possible from amongst all the choices. for example, 12 is closer to 10 than it is to 3, 4, or 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subtract columns, get absolute values and compare if equal or less like threshold, e.g. `2` and then set values in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Paid'] = np.where(df['Month_1'].sub(df['Month_2']).abs().le(2), 'Yes','')
print (df)
  Index  Month_1  Month_2 Paid
0    01       12       10  Yes
1    02        9        3     
2    03        2        4  Yes
3    04        1        8
```